# Fitting data to a B-spline in MATLAB

Tags: time-series, matlab, curve-fitting, bspline

I am trying to estimate missing values in time-series data which is in the form of a matrix. The columns represent the time points,i.e. Now, I want to fit each row of the matrix to a B-Spline, and use it to estimate the missing values. I could fit the data to a normal spline using MATLAB, but I am completely stuck at trying to figure out how to fit the data to create a B-Spline. Using the default bspline function in the Curve Fitting Toolbox lets me set the knot vector to the vector of time points, but I cannot set the control points, i.e. the elements of the row.
Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE ADDED**

The time-series data has rows that look like this:

```
-0.11    0.1    0.01    0.06    0.04   -0.26    0.04    0.19   -0.22    -0.2    0.12    0.21    -0.26    -0.3    0.22    0.58    -0.36    0.13
```

My knot vector is basically the time points, and it looks like this:

```
 0     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70    77    84    91    98   105   112   119
```

Basically I want to use each row along with the knot vector to construct a B-Spline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about these?

1. [Fast B-Spline class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32509-fast-b-spline-class)
2. [N-dimensional B-splines](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19632-n-dimensional-bsplines)
3. [B-Spline tools](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27047-b-spline-tools)
4. [splinefit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit)

Comment: I've seen some of them, but I'm rather confused as to how to actually use the functions, i.e. what should be the parameters to the function so that the row vector is fitted to the B-spline?

Comment: So why wont you add a sample matrix and ask a more specific question?

Comment: Added a sample row. Now, how do I go from such a row and a set of time points to a B-Spline?

Comment: Read and implement one of the examples that are available in the tools listed (for example in SPLINEFIT). It took me less than 2 minutes to produce what you wanted.